# solving non-linear equations using scipy

Tags: scipy

I'm trying to solve the following equation:

[image]

Where a list of A_e/A* values are given, and gamma=1.2, how should I solve this equation such that a list of M_e is returned corresponding to a list of A_e/A* values?
I thought about using `scipy.optimize.newton`, but it seems like this is not the right approach

```
def expr(x):
       
    result = np.arange(1,1.25,step=0.004)-((1/x)*((2/(1.2+1))*(1+((1.2-1)/2)*x**2))**((1.2+1)/(2*1.2-1)))
            
    return result.any()


scipy.optimize.newton(expr,1.1)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4660/3619719442.py in <module>
----> 1 scipy.optimize.newton(expr,1.1,x1=1.2)

D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\zeros.py in newton(func, x0, fprime, args, tol, maxiter, fprime2, x1, rtol, full_output, disp)
    338                             " Failed to converge after %d iterations, value is %s."
    339                             % (itr + 1, p1))
--> 340                         raise RuntimeError(msg)
    341                     warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
    342                 p = (p1 + p0) / 2.0

RuntimeError: Tolerance of 0.09999999999999987 reached. Failed to converge after 1 iterations, value is 1.2.
```

I used `x` to denote M_e, and I replaced Ae/A* with a list of values--`np.arange(1,1.25,step=0.004)` But, I guess the newton's method can only return 1 scalar value, but I defined the function with a sweeping list of Ae/A* values. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newton` works for scalar functions, and you are turning it into a vector function. Since you want the zero for different `Ae` values, include the `Ae` parameter in the function definition, then call `newton` several times (you can use the `args` keyword):

```
def expr(x, a):
    result = a-((1/x)*((2/(1.2+1))*(1+((1.2-1)/2)*x**2))**((1.2+1)/(2*1.2-1)))
    return result

[newton(expr, .01, args=(a,)) for a in np.arange(1,1.25,step=0.004)]

>>[0.9999999999999992, 0.9944379739232752,0.9889506795317498, 0.9835363421148852, ...
```

Comment: I have a follow-up quesiton. How can I force the results to be >1? This equation should theoretically return both a value less than 1 and a value larger than 1

Comment: with `newton` you need to specify x0 (`0.01` in the answer, you can change it). The only way to choose the x>1 solution is to set x0 so that the solution converges there. You can do it by choosing a reasonably large x0 (normally works), or choosing x0 so that xs < xm < x0, where xs is the first solution and xm is the position of the local maximum (or minimum) between both solutions

Comment: Alternatively you can use a bisect method (`scipy.optimize.brentq` works like bisect but is faster)

Comment: actually  I think I need to change the convergence guess x0 for each iteration, so I modified the code in the following way:```mach_exit_list=[scipy.optimize.newton(expr, tol=1.48e-6,maxiter=1000,args=(a,x)) for a in np.arange(2,50.5,step=0.5) & for x in np.arange(2,6.01,step=0.01)]```, however, this is not working. How should I incorporate both `x` and `a` in `args`?

Comment: try `[scipy.optimize.newton(expr, x0, tol=1.48e-6, maxiter=1000, args=(a,)) for a, x0 in zip(np.arange(2,50.5,step=0.5), np.arange(2,6.01,step=0.01) )]`